# grouping data by distinct dates using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a Message table that has fields namely `Creation_Date`, `Message_Count` and `Message_Cost`. I'm trying to group data by the dates but I want the dates to not repeat and then sum the total number of messages and message cost on each date row.
I've tried using the below expression but that doesn't resolve the issue.

```
var query = db.Messages
            .GroupBy(d => d.Creation_Date)
            .OrderBy(d => d.Key)
            .Select(g =>
            new Report
            {
                TotalMessagesSent = g.Select(t=>t.Message_Count).Distinct().Sum(),
                TotalCost = g.Select(p=>p.Customer_Price).Distinct().Sum(),
                DateTime = (DateTime)g.Key
            });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What results do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: I have the dates repeating.

Comment: I want distinctive date in each column

Comment: Then I suppose your dates aren´t that distinct as you think they are. Without showing any data, in particular what `Creation_Date` is on which your grouping relies, we can only guess.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing your `Creation_Date` includes a timestamp? If so, use `d.Creation_Date.Date` instead to group by the date component only.